# Ubuntu stuck on a black and white logo

Tags: boot

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. Today I installed the "Plank" dock. I removed it later and purged all the dependencies. Now, I'm not able to boot into Ubuntu. I'm not even able to get onto safe mode! 
I'm getting a black screen with white Ubuntu logo and that is where I'm stuck. 
I'm running a 17.10 Installation of Ubuntu. Any help would be appreciated!